# Timeline Banner - Is it possible to change using api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, banner

Can we change the banner using Graph API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Profile (timeline)Cover Edtiting via Api](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8070016/profile-timelinecover-edtiting-via-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API available to change the Timeline cover photo

You could upload a photo to another of the user's albums and get them to change it themselves?